# Inject Spel parameter on annotation parameter (like what is done with @Value on a field)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using this annotation provided by `spring-starter-elastic-search`to create a document and I would like to inject the parameter `indexname` dynamically:

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "myindex")
public class StockQuotation
```

In another bean I have successfully done that by using `@Value`on a field:

```
@Value("${elasticsearch.index.name}")
public String indexName;
```

However, I have tried to inject it in the same way in the annotation and the translation is not done:

```
@Entity
@Document(indexName = "${elasticsearch.index.name}")
public class StockQuotation
```

As I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException: [${elasticsearch.index.name}] missing
```

What would be the appropriate approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Resolved in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069670/spring-data-elasticsearch-document-indexname-defined-at-runtime. Hope it could helps.